# Exclude Duplicate Values in SUM with PeopleSoft Query

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, duplicates, peoplesoft

Complete noob here, so bear with me!...

I'm trying to write a query in *Oracle PeopleSoft* that is counting and summing an amount column of a table. The `COUNT` value works just fine; but because one of the tables joined in the query can have multiple values for each row of the table to which it is joined, the `SUM` is including multiple instances and giving overstated values. Here are the basics:

**TABLE A:** HEADER

**TABLE B:** LINE

**TABLE C:** ERROR_CODE (outer join to TABLE B)

I am trying to sum the `B.LINE_AMOUNT` for every unique `A.HEADER_ENTRY`; but because each voucher line could have more than one `C.ERROR_CODE`, the query is multiplying the `B.LINE_AMOUNT` by each rule.

**EXAMPLE** -- `HEADER_ENTRY #12345` has 4 lines totaling `$50` each, and line 3 has 2 error codes. When I run the query, the result for that entry is `$250` instead of the *actual* `$200`.

**Quick notes:**

- The actual query has 7 table records, and there are actually *two* different "error code" records (both of which are needed) -- both are on outer joins
- The `SUM` is conditional; so I'm currently using a `CASE WHEN` statement with it ->
   `SUM(CASE WHEN A.ENTRY_DATE < :2 THEN B.LINE_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END)`

EDIT: As requested, here is the sql as taken from the PeopleSoft query:

```
SELECT A.BUSINESS_UNIT, CASE WHEN (':6' = 'Y') AND ( A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR = 'M') THEN
C.MATCH_RULE_ID
WHEN (':6' = 'Y') AND ( A.VOUCHER_ID =  F.VOUCHER_ID) THEN
F.MATCH_RULE_ID
ELSE NULL END, A.ORIGIN, A.CLOSE_STATUS, A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR, COUNT( DISTINCT  A.VOUCHER_ID), SUM( CASE WHEN ( TO_CHAR(E.JOURNAL_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') < ':2') THEN  E.MONETARY_AMOUNT ELSE 0 END), TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')
  FROM PS_VOUCHER A, (PS_VOUCHER_LINE B LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_MTCH_RULE_OVRD C ON  B.BUSINESS_UNIT = C.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = C.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = C.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM ), ((PS_DISTRIB_LINE D LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_VCHR_ACCTG_LINE E ON  D.BUSINESS_UNIT = E.BUSINESS_UNIT AND D.VOUCHER_ID = E.VOUCHER_ID AND D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = E.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM AND D.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM = E.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM AND E.LEDGER = D.LEDGER AND E.SHIPTO_ID > ' ' ) LEFT OUTER JOIN  PS_AP_MTCH_EXCPTN F ON  E.BUSINESS_UNIT = F.BUSINESS_UNIT AND E.VOUCHER_ID = F.VOUCHER_ID AND E.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = F.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM ), PS_VENDOR G
  WHERE A.DELETE_DT IS NULL
     AND ( A.ENTERED_DT BETWEEN CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD')),'D') = 1) THEN
TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-2
WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD')),'D') = 2) THEN TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-3
ELSE TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-1 END AND CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:2,'YYYY-MM-DD')),'D') = 1) THEN
TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:2,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-2
WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:2,'YYYY-MM-DD')),'D') = 2) THEN TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:2,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-3
ELSE TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:2,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-1 END
     OR ( A.MATCHED_DT >= CASE WHEN (:9 = 'Y') THEN
NULL
WHEN ( A.CLOSE_STATUS = 'C') THEN
TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-1
ELSE TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD')) END
     AND A.ENTERED_DT <= CASE WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD')),'D') = 1) THEN
TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-2
WHEN (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD')),'D') = 2) THEN TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-3
ELSE TO_DATE(TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD'))-1 END))
     AND A.MATCH_ACTION = 'Y'
     AND ( A.MATCHED_DT > E.JOURNAL_DATE
     OR ( A.GROSS_AMT = 0
     AND A.MATCHED_DT > A.ENTERED_DT)
     OR ( A.ACCOUNTING_DT > A.ENTERED_DT
     AND A.MATCHED_DT > A.MATCH_DUE_DT)
     OR B.RECEIPT_DT > A.ENTERED_DT
     OR ( C.VOUCHER_ID IS NOT NULL
     AND A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR IN ('C','M','O'))
     OR F.VOUCHER_ID IS NOT NULL
     OR A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR NOT IN ('T','M','N'))
     AND ( A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR = CASE WHEN (:3 = 'N') AND (:4 = 'N') AND (:5 = 'N') THEN
A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR
WHEN (:3 = 'Y') THEN
'M'
ELSE NULL END
     OR C.MATCH_RULE_ID = CASE WHEN (:4 = 'Y') THEN
C.MATCH_RULE_ID
ELSE NULL END
     OR F.MATCH_RULE_ID = CASE WHEN (:4 = 'Y') THEN
F.MATCH_RULE_ID
ELSE NULL END)
     AND A.VENDOR_ID = CASE WHEN (:7 = ' ') THEN
A.VENDOR_ID
ELSE :7 END
     AND ( CASE WHEN (:6 = 'Y') AND ( A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR = 'M') THEN
C.MATCH_RULE_ID
WHEN (:6 = 'Y') AND ( A.VOUCHER_ID =  F.VOUCHER_ID) THEN
F.MATCH_RULE_ID
ELSE NULL END = :8
     OR A.VOUCHER_ID = CASE WHEN (:8 = ' ') THEN
A.VOUCHER_ID
ELSE NULL END)
     AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT = B.BUSINESS_UNIT
     AND A.VOUCHER_ID = B.VOUCHER_ID
     AND B.BUSINESS_UNIT = D.BUSINESS_UNIT
     AND B.VOUCHER_ID = D.VOUCHER_ID
     AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = D.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
     AND G.VENDOR_ID = A.VENDOR_ID
  GROUP BY  A.BUSINESS_UNIT,  CASE WHEN (':6' = 'Y') AND ( A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR = 'M') THEN
C.MATCH_RULE_ID
WHEN (':6' = 'Y') AND ( A.VOUCHER_ID =  F.VOUCHER_ID) THEN
F.MATCH_RULE_ID
ELSE NULL END,  A.ORIGIN,  A.CLOSE_STATUS,  A.MATCH_STATUS_VCHR
  ORDER BY 1, 5, 2
```

When run, I get a perfect count; but the sum ends up being overstated because the "MTCH_RULE_OVRD" and "AP_MTCH_EXCPTN" tables can have multiple "MATCH_RULE_ID"s for each. Not sure if I need a query hint or what... but I'm STUCK-Overflow!

I'm sure this is probably something really simple for you all! Thanks!

Comment: Hi, SQL would be useful to understand how are used those error records. thanks !

Comment: Thanks - SQL added above

Comment: you'll need to use an [inline view](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Inline_view) or a [with clause](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql99_with_clause.htm)

Comment: Thanks Conrad; but this is for a PeopleSoft query -- "FROM" clauses cannot be entered. (Also, I should note that we are currently on PeopleSoft 9.1 not 9.2)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wanted to know, I (regrettably) ended up having to resort to a SUBQUERY approach (I say "regrettably" because PeopleSoft 9.1 unfortunately has some issues with queries with multiple union/Subquery combinations that cause system session termination issues, which was why I was trying to avoid that approach). Still definitely interested if anyone has further insight on other ways to accomplish this; thanks